# Rename [phoenix-wright-aa] → [phoenix-wright-ace-attorney]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Given that we now have a 35 character tag limit, let's rename [phoenix-wright-aa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-aa) → [phoenix-wright-ace-attorney](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-ace-attorney).

I don't think that a tag synonym for the old game is necessary, given that if they type in `phoenix wright`, they'll find the tag easily enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

- [phoenix-wright-aa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-aa) → [phoenix-wright-ace-attorney](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-ace-attorney)

I also found and expanded the [phoenix-wright-dd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-dd) tag for *Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney: Dual Destinies*. Due to the length of the tag I added an extra synonym:

- [phoenix-wright-dd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-dd), [ace-attorney-dual-destinies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ace-attorney-dual-destinies) → [phoenix-wright-dual-destinies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-dual-destinies)